# On Change select menu add result into database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hello I am trying to make a `<select>` menu from which when you select some of the options the selected option to be writen inside the database using Ajax, here is what I have acomplished so far:

this is my select menu:

```
  <select name="status">
  <option value="">Select option:</option>
  <option value="aproved">aproved</option>
  <option value="canceled">canceled</option>
  </select>
```

Here is my java script which should select the change and send it to the backend php file where the database conection and the UPDATE query are, the select method is ot working ot it is not updating imediately after a selection is done. The Goal is once a user make a selection the result to go inside the database withoud the need of pressing button or doing anything else.

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('select[name=status]').change(function(){

      selectstatus = $("select[name=status]").val();   

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "selectbackend.php",
        data: {"selectstatus": selectstatus
       },
        })
        .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){alert(textStatus);})
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){alert(jqXHR+"--"+textStatus+"--"+errorThrown);});
});//end change
});//end ready
</script>
```

but it is not working either is giving any error, my suspicions are that the java script is not working in some way.

here is backend file:

```
<?php
$selectstatus = $_POST['selectstatus'];
$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {echo "No connection" . mysqli_connect_error();}

    $query = " UPDATE test
           SET var = '$slectstatus'
           WHERE id='1";
```

Comment: Looks like the variable selectstatus only is specified inside the if statement scope, i.e. you can't access it outside of it as it is defined inside of it. I would get rid of the if statement as it doesn't make any sence to have it due to that the event is registered with the same selector as the if statement.

Comment: if clause removed still not working, edited in the code above

Comment: have u got any errors in your firebug console..??

Comment: what I get on firebug is: ReferenceError: $ is not defined
 

$(document).ready(function(e) {

Comment: @JohnSiniger
You might need to include the jQuery Library to use $.ajax or **$** selector. Include this inside your **<head></head>** 
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: flyingDuck  that fixed the problem thanks ! I don't know how to select it as ANSWER since it is in the comments section.

Comment: Awesome! I added an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<html>
    <select id="status" name="status">
       <option value="">Select option:</option>
       <option value="aproved">aproved</option>
       <option value="canceled">canceled</option>
    </select>
</html>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#status').change(function(){

    //var selectstatus = $("select[name=status]").val();   

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "selectbackend.php",
        data: {"selectstatus": $(this).val()},
    })
    .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){alert(textStatus);})
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){alert(jqXHR+"--"+textStatus+"--                                      +errorThrown);});
});//end change
});//end ready
</script>
```

Then:

```
<?php
$selectstatus = addslashes($_POST['selectstatus']);
$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {echo "No connection" . mysqli_connect_error();}

$query = " UPDATE test
       SET var = '$selectstatus'
       WHERE id='1'";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('select[name=status]').change(function(){

      selectstatus = $("select[name=status]").val();   

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "selectbackend.php",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",       
        data: JSON.stringify({"selectstatus": selectstatus}),
        })
        .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){alert(textStatus);})
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){alert(jqXHR+"--"+textStatus+"--"+errorThrown);});
});//end change
});//end ready
</script>
```